# The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: reporting-services

I created a report project in Visual Studio 2015 and deployed it and got the URL without errors and it worked in INTERNET EXPLORER. I got the reports on the first day but the next day I got an error

> The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation (rsAccessDenied)

Then I changed the internet explorer local intranet settings (user authentication --> logon) but didn't get the reports.

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: Check if user running VS is added to SSRS users, and that permissions granted to him. You probably running IE under different users, or SSRS settings changed.

Comment: @grafgenerator can you please post me the steps in granting user permissions.

Comment: Check this two tutorials - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337385(v=sql.105).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337471(v=sql.105).aspx
Give your user System User and System Admin roles, and grant everything available in folder permissions.

Comment: @grafgenerator when i run my report manager URL in the browser i get an error called (User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.) how to overcome this ?

Comment: Try to run browser as admin, if you didn't already do that. Also, try to temporary disable UAC.

Comment: @grafgenerator Thank U very much....I got my reports in internet explorer. But I am not able to get it in google chrome.

Comment: So the issue is with access rights. Open reports portal in IE and go to Settings. On the settings page, go to Security tab, and add your domain\user as administrator. Then go to reports page again, click Manage Folder and on Security tab add your domain\user to list with all available permissions granted.

Comment: @grafgenerator Got my reports in chrome finally. Thank u for helping me to sort out issues. :)

Comment: I will post an answer, so you will be able to mark it as accepted:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant access rights to user you're accessing the reports server. 
There are MSDN tutorials for that: [1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337385(v=sql.105).aspx), [2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337471(v=sql.105).aspx), but short steps are:

- Open reports portal.
- Go to Settings page -> Security tab, and add your domain\user to the list of users as administrator.
- Go to reports page again.
- Click Manage folder, on opened page open Security tab.
- Add your domain\user to the list of users with all available premissions.

If you can't open reports portal in Chrome, try to access it in IE, and if it's not working, try to run IE as administrator.