# Can user permission to SSRS 2019 be changed or overruled without admin access?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2019

I tried to download documents in bulk from a SSRS 2019 server by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783093/download-all-ssrs-reports) stackoverflow thread.

Unfortunately I do not have sufficient permissions as can be seen from the prompt below:

```
Failed to retrieve item definition of '/directory' from proxy: Exception calling "GetItemDefinition" with "1" argument(s): "The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'domain\username' are insufficient for performing this operation." At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ReportingServicesTools\0.0.7.2\Functions\CatalogItems\Out-RsCatalogItem.ps1:117 char:17
+ ...             throw (New-Object System.Exception("Failed to retrieve it ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to retrieve item definition of '/directory' from proxy:  exception calling "GetItemDefinition" with "1" argument(s): "The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'domain\user' are insufficient for performing this operation.
```

I have tried many of the proposed solutions on stackoverflow such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559275/the-permissions-granted-to-the-user-are-insufficient-to-perform-this-operation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395286/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation). However, due to my permission level the properties tab and security tab are missing, the settings option itself is greyed out, all can be seen below:
[image: Overall bar]
[image: Settings]

When I try to enter http:domain/reports/manage/security/browse it prompts:
[image: User prompt]

And also when I try to go to http:domain/reports/manage/site/general it prompts:
[image: Lack of security settings]

However, I do have access to quite some reports present in the ReportServer overview, but not all it seems.

1. How can I specifically download the files **i do have access to** with Windows PS without getting the user access prompt as shown earlier which followed after:

   ```
   Out-RsFolderContent -Proxy $proxy -RsFolder / -Destination 'C:\SSRS_Out' -Recurse
   ```
2. Is there any method to circumvent access permissions to download all SSRS server files without having access to any admin account?

Comment: Do you have any access to the SQL Server DB? You could query and export there if so. Otherwise, you can try using specific folder paths with `Out-RsFolderContent -RsFolder /My/Folder`. The web service url (not Report *Manager* URL) should give you a list of everything available to your user: e.g. http://server/ReportServer

Comment: I do not have direct access to the SQL server DB. in the ReportServer there are three main folders visible, running code shown in question returns all folders but no files, running specific folder prompts: ```Failed to retrieve items in '/My/Folder/': Exception calling "ListChildren" with "2" argument(s): "The path of
the item '/My/Folder/' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions
apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. --->``` This still returns all subfolders but no files in them

Comment: I know the SQL server name and IP domain, is it perhaps possible to connect directly to the SQL database through bash?

Comment: **IF** you have permission to connect, then `sqlcmd` is probably the simplest way. For example:  `sqlcmd -S server01 -Q "SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases"`. It is a microsoft tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility . It sounds like you may need to contact whoever manages SSRS to give you permissions though